# How do I write special characters to csv file in node with fast-csv

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, nodes, fast-csv

I have a list that contains German characters and I write to csv file with fast-csv and gives me different characters.

```
import { writeToPath } from "fast-csv";

const data = [
  {
    "name": "Ästhetik Zahnarzt Hamburg City Z-24 Mö 17 / Dr. P. Michaelis, Dr. C. Khorram",
    "street_number": "Speersort 8",
    "zip_location": "20095 Hamburg, City Innenstadt",
    "phone": "040 34 45 44",
    "website": "http://www.z-24.de",
    "area": "Branche: Zahnärzte"
  }
]

writeToPath("tmp.csv", data, { headers: true })
  .on("error", (err) => console.error(err))
  .on("finish", () => console.log("Done writing."));
```

output is this:
[screenshot of output data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdZNX.png)

`Ã„sthetik Zahnarzt Hamburg City Z-24 MÃ¶ 17 / Dr. P. Michaelis, Dr. C. Khorram | ... | Branche: ZahnÃ¤rzte`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the Excel issue with guessing a CSV encoding.
Just indicate the option `writeBOM` equals to `true`, that way Excel can guess that the encoding is UTF-8.
The most reliable way is to write to XLSX-file directly to avoid such encoding issues.

Comment: It was kinda strange because if I opened the csv file with vscode it showed the correct characters. But excel had those issues.
You were correct and `writeBOM: true` worked.
Thank you.

Comment: writeBOM: true worked too